# To count a character in files by Find/Xargs/Sed

Tags: count, sed, find, xargs

**How can you count the number of the character `<` in your files?**

I am trying to count the number of the character "<" in my files, similarly as in Vim by

```
%s/<//gn
```

I run

```
 find * -type f | xargs sed 's/<//gn'
```

I get

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unknown option to `s'
```

This error suggests me that Vim's :s -mode is not like SED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `n` option in Vim, but yes, sed does not support the `n` option.  Here's another way you could count the number of instances of the `<` character in your files:

```
find * -type f | xargs cat | tr -d -c '<' | wc -c
```

The `tr -d -c '<'` command deletes all characters that are not `<`, and then `wc -c` counts the number of remaining characters.

Comment: **Does this `find * -type f | xargs cat | tr -d -c '<'` replace nearly everything in my files?**

Comment: No, it does not touch your files -- it prints them out to a pipe with cat, and then the pipe is filtered.  The original files are not modified.

Comment: Let's assume that I remove this `cat |`. **How does the command change?**

Comment: Then it doesn't work, because `tr` doesn't accept filenames -- it *only* reads and writes from stdin and stdout respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -RoE "<" * |wc -l
```